# Read permissions for intent-filter

Tags: android, android-permissions

I have an app that makes use of the `getExternalFilesDir()` directory, so I have the correct permissions specified in my manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
     android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
     android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
```

I specify the maxSdkVersion because as of API 19, `getExternalFilesDir()` no longer requires these permissions.

I also have an `intent-filter` defined to allow users to open PDF files with my app in order to import them (which, in turn, makes a copy of it and puts it in my app specific directory).

```
final Uri pdfUri = intent.getData();  // intent is from getIntent()
InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(pdfUri); // Error is here
```

Now, since I added the `maxSdkVersion` value to my permission, whenever I try to import a PDF on API 19+ (from my downloads folder), I get a neat `Permission Denied` error.

```
W/System.err﹕ java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/field test v13.pdf: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:496)
W/System.err﹕ at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
W/System.err﹕ at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103)
W/System.err﹕ at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:660)
W/System.err﹕ at com.myapp.ImportPDF$1.onClick(ImportPDF.java:96)
```

How can I get permission to read a file that the user specifically asked my app to deal with? Surely there's something to handle cases like these, but I'm having a hard time finding anything on it.

Comment: Please provide [a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating your problem. In this case, that would include the Java stack trace pertaining to your error, along with the Java code referred to from that trace.

Answer (score 0):

For reading from user's device you need the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission on all the api levels. The only case that you wouldn't need it is if the app you launch to give you the reference, gives it back as a `content` URI and not `file` URI. Also if you want to write your files on anywhere other than your application folder, you need `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and if you need to ask for `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` then the you also get READ permission automatically.

From 23 (6.0) and above, you are required to ask these permissions in runtime and for doing so you can use [this library](https://github.com/kayvannj/PermissionUtil) to help you with it.